# Setting empty values from a Laravel form from the model

Tags: laravel-5.3

In my customers model I have the following two functions, that handle fields that are empty, when a new customer is created:

```
public function setCustPstAttribute($custpst)
{
    $this->attributes['CustPST'] = trim($custpst) == '' ? 0 : trim($custpst);
}

    public function setCustSicAttribute($custsiccode){
    $this->attributes['CustSicCode'] = trim($custsiccode) == '' ? 0 : trim($custsiccode);
}
```

The function setCustPstAttribute($custpst) works fine, you can see the 0 value above. The setCustSicAttribute($custsiccode) function will not be accessed/entered at all, I tried exiting from the function, and it is never accessed.  The only difference is the variable type, $custpst is varchar and $custsiccode is int. The sql insert is looking for an integer, but gets an empty string.

```
QueryException {#363 ▼
  #sql: "insert into `customers` (`CustCompanyName`, `CustSicCode`, `FOBLocation`, `CustPST`, `CustGenerator`, `CustStatus`, `CustLastUpdate`, `CustStartDate`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
  #bindings: array:8 [▼
    0 => "Test"
    1 => ""
    2 => "Selkirk"
    3 => 0
    4 => ""
    5 => "Active"
    6 => "2017-02-10 14:12:48"
    7 => "2017-02-10 14:12:48"
  ]
  #message: "SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'CustSicCode' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `customers` (`CustCompanyName`, `CustSicCode`, `FOBLocation`, `CustPST`, `CustGenerator`, `CustStatus`, `CustLastUpdate`, `CustStartDate`) values (fgfgf, , Selkirk, 0, , Active, 2017-02-10 14:12:48, 2017-02-10 14:12:48))"
  #code: "22007"
  #file: "/var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php"
  #line: 770
  -previous: PDOException {#364 ▶}
  +errorInfo: array:3 [▼
    0 => "22007"
    1 => 1366
    2 => "Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'CustSicCode' at row 1"
  ]
  +"previous": PDOException {#364 ▶}
  -trace: {▶}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the function(between set and Attribute) has to be exactly the same as column name in database. set**CustSicCode**Attribute. After updating it worked. Thanks